# Instagram and Twitter Hashtag analytics

Tags: api, twitter, instagram

How do services like Keyhole, Minter and Union Metrics determine the # of impressions and reach of a particular hashtag for their analytics reports?  This data isn't available via Instagram or Twitter's APIs.  So are they just making estimates based on # of followers?  Minter in particular looks look a stab in the dark as they give a range that is always something like somewhere between 500 and 500,000!

Answer (score 0):

Both Keyhole and Union Metrics use the same formula to count the impression and reach of a hashtag.

Impression:
As per them the impression is the total number of views of a conversation / tweets containing hashtag. They directly multiply the number of tweets from an account with its followers.

Formula to calculate impression: (Number of tweets from account-1 * number of followers of that account) + (Number of tweets from account-2 * number of followers of that account).

Reach:
Reach can be defined as the number of accounts, the tweets containing the hashtag has reached.

Formula to calculate reach: Impressions - repeated users

The result varies highly when we compare these metrics with the metrics of Twitter analytics, but still they are useful.